# Can the sort order in the review tab be added for all the time tabs?

Tags: feature-request, review, sorting

In the review tab, under "first answers", "low quality" etc... for the "day" tab, there is a sort order box:
[image]
However, under "week", "month", etc. there is no such ordering. Can this be added to the other time tabs?

Comment: Where is this? These sortings do not show up for me anywhere on SO.

Comment: I don't see this at all either

Comment: @animuson, in review in the bottom right hand corner where they're as unnoticeable as possible

Comment: @Ben: Ah, you have to turn off random sorting.

Comment: @animuson, now it's my turn to be confused. How do you turn _on_ random sorting :-). I've never changed the order at all.

Comment: @Ben: All the way at the bottom of the page, there's a link. `Showing posts in order (enable random ordering)`

Comment: Thanks @animuson, I don't have that on meta (where I was looking) must be rep related.

Comment: I don't believe you can use it if there's less than like 100 posts or something.

Comment: So does this mean that you guys *do* have it or not?